# How to force Word to do a SaveAs on generated document

Tags: ms-word, office-automation

We have a system where we are generating a report as a Word document (using RDLC).

The report is created in a temporary directory, and then Word is launched to display it to the user.

Word is launched, and the report loaded by:

```
_wordApplication = (Word.Application)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application"));
object tempFileNameObj = documentPath;
_wordDocument = _wordApplication.Documents.Open(ref tempFileNameObj);
```

What I want is to convince Word that this is really a newly created, unsaved file, so it will give the user a SaveAs dialog when they save it (rather than save back to the temporary location).

Ideally, I would like to be able to specify the target directory, and offer a default name.

While the Word is being launched, I can do what I like using Automation, but after Word has been launched, my application will be disconnected from Word, and I would prefer not to leave any macros floating around in the document.

Comment: Hi you can take a look at: http://johniekarr.wordpress.com/2012/09/15/forcing-save-as-in-microsoft-word/ I think it's pretty close to what you want

Comment: @SamuelLopez: Some good stuff there, but shipping a Word Add-in isn't really an option. If I have to resort to including macros in the document then the approach there would be useful.

Comment: If you can use .New instead of .Open, that should force creation of a new document. In recent versions of Windows Word, that works even when  tempFileNameobj is a document rather than a template, but I can't remember whether that was always the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using a macro I believe that the only way to archieve this would be to save the file that they will download be a read-only or user defined template file this way if they wan't to make changes to it they wil have to save it with another name in their computer to save the changes made. If you can use a macro you can archieve more options and even force a save as dialog when the document is opened or when it's closed. I hope this helps as I couldn't find any more information without using a macro.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename your `.doc` file to `.dot` (Word Template) and if you launch it afterwards, it will create a new File looking exactely like your `.doc`